# Is it better to nest setTimeout()s or just increase their time?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, timer, settimeout

Lets say I wanted to have a function, which when executed, after 3 seconds console logs "Hey." and after 2 more seconds console logs "Hey again.".

This could be done in 2 ways:

The first way:

```
(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Hey.");
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("Hey again.");
        },2000);
    },3000);
})();
```

In this one, we set a 3 second timer, when the 3 seconds pass, we console log "Hey", and we set a new, 2 second timer. When the 2 seconds pass, we console log "Hey again.".

The second way:

```
(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Hey.");
    },3000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("Hey again.");
    },5000)
})();
```

In this one, we set a 3 second timer that console logs "Hey." and we set a 5 second timer that console logs "Hey again.". Both timers are set **at the same time** because JavaScript is asynchronous. And they both start **executing at the same time**, so when the 3 seconds from the first timer pass, the second timer has only 2 seconds left because it was running at the same time as the first timer.

Which way is a "better practice"?

Comment: I think it depends on your needs.

Comment: The first will run the second routine around 2s after the first one, whenever that might be--it could be 3s later, or 3.000001, or 3.1, or 4, or 30. The second will attempt to run the two tasks as close as possible to 3 and 5 seconds from now. So if you want the second task to be relative to the first, use your first alternative. If you want the second task to be relative to now, use your second alternative.

Comment: (Where 3 and 5 seconds could be x.1, x+1, or 30.. if the differences are that big or critical then neither approach is a finished solution. In fact, most animations will use the former [or a setInterval] and some form of bias/difference calculation or interpolation.)

Comment: Consider a) what happens when `console.log("Hey.");` is computation-heavy and takes 1 second b) what happens when `console.log("Hey.");` throws an exception c) how easily you refactor each solution if now the second log should depend on the results of the first. Now decide what you need.

Comment: @Bergi So, if I want the second log to depend of the result of the first, a better solution would be the first one?

Comment: @aCodingN00b: Exactly. If they are completely independent (and you expect that to never change), you should use independent timeouts. Otherwise nest them. Imo, even "do this and then that" is a dependency, even if not obvious from the code.